# Issue with wp_insert_post() when post_content contains links?

Tags: wp-insert-post, post-content

When I create a post using `wp_insert_post()` if the `post_content` contains an HTML link I'm getting a copy of the `post_content` in the `<head>` and the `<body>` of my post HTML page.

The strange thing is when I add an HTML img to the `post_content` it works fine. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

In a nutshell, I have posts that I am using as templates. The template ID's are stored in an array called `$array_of_post_templates` and I run them through a foreach loop to get the post_title and `post_content` from each template and then insert that data into its own post using  `wp_insert_post()`

```
foreach ($array_of_post_templates as $post_temp) {

            $query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID LIKE {$post_temp}");

            $post_title = $query->post_title;
            $post_content = $query->post_content;


            $arg = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_title' => $post_title,
                'post_content' => $post_content,
                'post_category' => array($post_cat),
                'post_status'   => $pub_status,
                'comment_status' => 'closed'
            );

            $new_post = wp_insert_post($arg);
```

Example of basic HTML link I am trying to insert:

```
<a href="https://google.com">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more debugging I realized the problem was being caused by another file in my plugin and the above `wp_insert_post()` code above is working correctly. I guess that explains why I couldn't find anyone else having this problem.

So the CORRECT ANSWER is... if you are working on a plugin and all else fails, try deactivating your plugin to see if the issue goes away.

On a side note, it's always amazing how sometimes just taking the time to type out your problem in question form helps you to solve your own problems. :)